# do not read first line of file in awk command file

Tags: awk, command

I am having trouble making it so that my list of awk commands does not read the first line of a data file. It must read each line except for the first, and then concatenate the athlete and year into a string. Later in the program I use an array, I did not list all of the code. The first two lines of the data file are listed below.  I need to make it so it does not read the heading line and only starts with the first athlete. Any help on this would be great!

Script:

```
BEGIN{
FS=","
cnt=0; sum=0;
}
{
name=$1
year=$4
ayStr = name "," " " year
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NR > 1` before the block that processes the file lines:

```
BEGIN {
FS=","
cnt=0; sum=0;
}
NR > 1 {
name=$1
year=$4
ayStr = name "," " " year
```

`NR` is the line number in the file, so it only processes lines after 1

Comment: I tried this and now when I invoke the awk command file it will print the contents of the file without the first line and then print what I have in my END block. Also it still included the first line when it printed my array in the END block. I need it to just print my output and not the contents of the file.

Comment: @XpLoiTs the problem you are describing now exists in some part of your script that you haven't shown us or told us anything about so we can't help you with that.

Comment: But you didn't do what @Barmar suggested so of course you're still having a problem. Indenting code by use of different amounts of white space at the start of lines makes it easier to read, btw.

Comment: I did try it. It did not do what I needed it to. That is why I didn't post it in the original code.

Comment: But it IS the right answer to your specific question so if it didn't do what you want then either you implemented it correctly but what you really want is something different than what you've described so far, or you didn't implement it correctly. Either way, without seeing what you did we can't help you. Also, edit your question to show your expected output plus the output you are actually getting.

Comment: I bet I know what you did. I bet you put the `NR>1` test on the line preceeding the line that contains the opening `{` instead of putting it on the same line as the `{` as @Barmar shows. White space matters to awk - by doing what I think you did you are telling awk to print every line except the first (that's what a line just containing `NR>1` means) AND to additionally execute your existing block of code for every line.

Comment: This was the problem. Once I moved it on the same line as the { it worked correctly. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar mentions you can test `NR>1` to skip the first line but why skip it when you can use it? Do this instead and you don't need to hard-code the field numbers in your script, just access them by the value they have on the first line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="," }

NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}

{
    ayStr = $(f["Athlete"]) ", " $(f["Year"])
    print ayStr

    print "----"

    for (name in f) {
        value = $(f[name])
        print name " = " value
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Yannick Agnel, 2012
----
Silver Medals = 1
Total Medals = 3
Athlete = Yannick Agnel
Gold Medals = 2
Closing Ceremony Date = 8/12/2012
Year = 2012
Age = 20
Bronze Medals = 0
Sport = Swimming
Country = France
```

Comment: Would it not be better to do a for loop so they are in the correct order ?

Comment: The current loop is just to show the OP what fields are present, I suspect the OP doesn't need to do that loop on all fields at all but is instead just using specific named fields in the rest of his code.